# Drawing widget class won't draw when added to existing code Kivy Python

Tags: python, class, kivy, widget, drawing

Everything from MyGridLayout(Widget) works fine. The drawing box for the DrawingWidget shows up, but does not draw a line. If I put the DrawingWidget in it's own solo program it allows me to draw just fine. Is there something wrong with the placement of the class? I have tried many arrangements of the KV document and am only able to get the drawing box to appear below all my other widgets from MyGridLayout that function fine.

```
class MyGridLayout(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass
class DrawingWidget(Widget):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(DrawingWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            with self.canvas:
                Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
                self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size,
                                    pos=self.pos)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_rectangle,
                    size=self.update_rectangle)

        def update_rectangle(self, instance, value):
            self.rect.pos = self.pos
            self.rect.size = self.size

        def on_touch_down(self, touch):
            super(DrawingWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)

            if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                return

            with self.canvas:
                Color(0, 0, 0, 1)
                self.line = Line(points=[touch.pos[0], touch.pos[1]], width=2)

        def on_touch_move(self, touch):
            if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                return

            self.line.points = self.line.points + [touch.pos[0], touch.pos[1]]              
                    

class funcswspinnerall(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    funcswspinnerall().run()
```

And here is an abbreviated KV file

```
<MyGridLayout>:
    ScrollView:
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            padding:9,9,9,9
          
            GridLayout:
                cols:3
                size_hint_y:.5
                Label:
                Button:
                    text:'Enter Activity'
                    on_press:root.sendmatt()
                    size_hint_x:3
                    size_hint_y:1
                Label:
            GridLayout:
                cols:1
                DrawingWidget:
                    
<DrawingWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `DrawingWidget` inside a `ScrollView`. The `ScrollView` wants to use the mouse touches for scrolling, so there is an interference with your drawing. The fix is to either move the `DrawingWidget` out of the `ScrollView` or add:

```
scroll_type: ['bars']
```

to the `ScrollView`, which limits your scrolling to using the scroll bars.